# Implementing multiple headers in SwiftUI

Tags: list, swiftui, header

Hope everyone is doing great
I’d like to ask for some help concerning headers in swiftui
I’ve made an app and i have added categories, so therefore i need headers to seperate my data
however, it’s not doing what I want! (typical... :joy:)

Would a kind soul help a lost soul find the path of enlightenment?

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @State private var isShowingSettings: Bool = false
    
    var fruit: [Fruit] = fruitData
    var driedFruit: [DriedFruit] = driedFruitData
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: fruitHeader) {
                    ForEach(fruit, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailView(fruit: item)) {
                            FruitRowView(fruit: item)
                                .padding(.vertical, 4)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section(header: driedFruitHeader) {
                    ForEach(fruit, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailView(driedFruit: item)) {
                            FruitRowView(driedFruit: item)
                                .padding(.vertical, 4)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("Category")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                    Button(action: {
                                        isShowingSettings = true
                                    }) {
                                        Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                                    } //: BUTTON
                                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSettings, content: {
                                        SettingsView()
                                    })
            )
        } //: NAVIGATION
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
​
    var fruitHeader: some View {
        Text("Fruits").padding(.leading, -10)
    }
​
    var driedFruitHeader: some View {
        Text("Dried fruits").padding(.leading, -10)
    }
}
// MARK: - PREVIEW
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(fruit: fruitData, driedFruit: driedFruitData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you'd like to see happening vs. what you're experiencing?

Comment: I have created 2 file of data (FruitData & DriedFruitData). In oder to different them I want to create headers. FruitData passes but not DriedFruitData. It gives me this error "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" and down at var fruitHeader and var driedFruitHeader it gives me thse 2 errors "Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration - Expected '{' in body of function declaration - Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration Insert 'func '"

Comment: @Doodi just remove these two var and delete extra space and agian add it will fix

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass driedFruit array in ForEach

```
List {
    Section(header: fruitHeader) {
        ForEach(fruit, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailView(fruit: item)) {
                FruitRowView(fruit: item)
                    .padding(.vertical, 4)
            }
        }
    }
    Section(header: driedFruitHeader) {
        ForEach(driedFruit, id: \.self) { item in //<--Here
            NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailView(driedFruit: item)) {
                FruitRowView(driedFruit: item)
                    .padding(.vertical, 4)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work :( I still have the same errors

Comment: @Doodi for breaking the error you need to separate your code and for Expected '(' in argument  you just need to remove both var and try to rewrite code.